# Do sites using Paypal's chained-payments API need to be approved before using them in production?

Tags: paypal

It is unclear from their documentation if websites are required to go through the same approval process that other apps that use the adaptive payments API do. Does anyone know an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes you do, but the review process is not very onerous.